# How ActiveMQ guarantee msg sent at least once?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a producer send msg to a ActiveMQ broker, and a consumer subscribe from the same topic. I know that the broker can persist the msg, so as soon as the msg reaches the broker, it can be guaranteed available for the consumer. (right?)

But what happen if the network between producer and ActiveMQ broker is broken, in this case is there a way to guarantee the at-least-once sent? like, the producer itself can persist msg before sending to the ActiveMQ broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the guarantee to be established the message must reach the broker, if the network is down then the burden is on you to capture the send error and retry the send at a later time.  The ActiveMQ client offers no persistent storage for what it sends, you can use the failover transport and the client will retry the send on reconnect but it the application is shutdown and you haven't provided some means of recovery on restart then there isn't anything more the client can do.

Comment: Thanks, I would implement a local persist queue to fix this.